# Binary XML file line 13: You must supply a layout_width attribute

Tags: android, xml

I'm trying to incorporate the [SquareCamera library](https://github.com/boxme/SquareCamera) into my Android app.  I'm currently getting the error `Binary XML file line #13: You must supply a layout_width attribute.` when I try to open up a Fragment View.  I believe it's referring to these lines in the layout file:

```
<com.desmond.squarecamera.SquareCameraPreview
    android:id="@+id/camera_preview_view"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"/>

<View
    android:id="@+id/cover_top_view"
    android:layout_width="@dimen/squarecamera__cover_start_width"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@id/camera_preview_view"
    android:background="@android:color/black"/>
```

(Line 13 specifically is the start of the View tag).\

As you can see, the height is specified.  What is going wrong?

Comment: Does that dimension resource exist? What is its value?

Comment: Your link is bad for the `Square camera library`. Edit it. And show your dimensions. Also you have two underscores between **squarecamera** and **cover**. Maybe that's causing the error weirdly somehow.

Answer (score 0):

There seems to be nothing wrong with your code. The problem must be with *@dimen/squarecamera__cover_start_width*

Try this:

> android:layout_width="match_parent" or android:layout_width="20dp" or
>   set any value.

Answer (score 0):

maybe it is because in your width attribute you have two underscores....check with the resource